# Use of re.MULTILINE and re.DOTALL together python

Tags: python, regex

Basically the input files goes like this:

> >U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete
>
> ```
>        cds. #some records don't have this line (see below)
>
>        Length = 2575
> ```
>
> (some text)
>
> >U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete
>
> ```
>        Length = 2575
> ```
>
> (some text)
>
> (etc...)

Now I wrote this to extract the line that starts with > and the number for length

```
import re
regex = re.compile("^(>.*)\r\n.*Length\s=\s(\d+)", re.MULTILINE)
match = regex.findall(sample_blast.read())

print match[0]
```

which works fine for extracting records when the Length line is the next line to the > line.

Then I tried re.DOTALL which should make any record match (.*Length) regardless if there is an extra line or not.

```
regex = re.compile("^(>.*)\r\n.*(?:\r\n*.?)Length\s=\s(\d+)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

But it does not work. I tried re.MULTILINE and re.DOTALL instead of pipe, but still does not work.

So the question is how to create a regex that match the records and return the desired group regardless of the extra line in record or not. Would be nice if someone can show this in re.VERBOSE as well. Sorry for the long post and thanks for any help in advance. :)

Comment: Are you certain that the `>` is the first character on the line? Also, are there really only `\r\n` line endings or are `\n` line endings an option? If you open `sample_blast` in `r` text mode then python may have translated these for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is likely your use of `\r\n`. Instead, try using only `\n`:

```
>>> x = """
... >U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete
... 
...        cds. #some records don't have this line (see below)
... 
...        Length = 2575
... (some text)
... 
... >U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete
... 
...        Length = 2575
... (some text)
... 
... (etc...)
... """
>>> re.search("^(>.*)\n.*(?:\n*.?)Length\s=\s(\d+)", x, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10c937e00>
>>> _.group(2)
'2575'
```

Additionally, your first `.*` is too greedy. Instead, try using: `^(>.*?)$.*?Length\s=\s(\d+)`:

```
>>> re.findall("^(>.*?)$.*?Length\s=\s(\d+)", x, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
[('>U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete', '2575'), ('>U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete', '2575')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
"^(>[^\r\n]*).*?Length\s=\s(\d+)"
```

With both options set (using the pipe notation).

The first capturing group will match everything up to first line break after `>` (independently of your operating system). Then the `.*?` will match any characters until the **first** `Length` encountered. The rest is the same as your first attempt.

The problem with your former attempt seems to be, that you use `.*` which can match anything and is greedy at the same time (so it will consume as much as it can, including the following `Length = 2575`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
sample_blast = """
>U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete

       cds. #some records don't have this line (see below)

       Length = 2575
(some text)

>U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete

       Length = 2575
(some text)

(etc...)
"""
import re
regex = re.compile("^>(.*?)Length\s=\s(\d+)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
match = regex.findall(sample_blast)

print(match)
```

```
[("U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete\n\n       cds. #some records don't have this line (see below)\n\n       ", '2575'),
 ('U51677 Human non-histone chromatin protein HMG1 (HMG1) gene, complete\n\n       ', '2575')]
```